# Unattended upgrades doesn't upgrade additional repository

Tags: package-management, unattended-upgrades

Unattended upgrades doesn't upgrade additional repository. For other packages the upgrade does work. This are the settings which I made:

```
> cat  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades // Automatically
> upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs // // Note that in
> Ubuntu security updates may pull in new dependencies // from
> non-security sources (e.g. chromium). By allowing the release //
> pocket these get automatically pulled in.
> Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
>         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
>         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
>         // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
>         // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
>         // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
>         // should also install from here by default.
>         "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
>         "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
>         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
> 
>
```

And here:

```
>  cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
> APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
> APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

But also after some time there are some packages which hasn't updated (there are also not hold):

```
> apt list --upgradable Listing... Done icinga2-bin/icinga-focal
> 2.12.1-1.focal amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12.0-1.focal] icinga2-common/icinga-focal 2.12.1-1.focal all [upgradable from:
> 2.12.0-1.focal] icinga2-doc/icinga-focal 2.12.1-1.focal all [upgradable from: 2.12.0-1.focal] icinga2/icinga-focal 2.12.1-1.focal
> amd64 [upgradable from: 2.12.0-1.focal]
```

These packages are from an additional repository:

```
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll total 12 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep
> 14 08:27 ./ drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Sep 14 08:27 ../
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   57 Sep 14 08:27 icinga-main-focal.list
```

Please let me know how will the unattended Upgrades completely work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unattended upgrades uses the format `"Origin:Section";` Here's an example.

```
//    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
Origin  = ${distro_id}
Section = ${distro_codename}-updates
```

So we need to:

1. Find the Origin field,
2. Find the Section field, then
3. Wrap those in the correct formatting.

---

**Step 1**: Find the URL of the source that you want to add. It's located in your apt sources. It's inside your file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/icinga-main-focal.list` The URL looks something like this...

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
  ...or...
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  ...or...
deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public main
```

**Step 2**: Find the corresponding Release file in your system for the URL.

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security
  ...becomes...
/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease


http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable
  ...becomes...
/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_InRelease


https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public
  ...becomes...
/var/lib/apt/lists/downloads.plex.tv_repo_deb_dists_public_Release
```

**Step 3**: Use grep to find the "Origin" field.

```
$ grep Origin /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease
Origin: Ubuntu

$ grep Origin /var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_InRelease
Origin: Google LLC

$ grep Origin /var/lib/apt/lists/downloads.plex.tv_repo_deb_dists_public_Release
Origin: Artifactory
```

**Step 4**: Find the Section field.

Go back to the URL in Step 1. The Section is simply the first word after the URL.

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security
  ...becomes...
Section: focal-security


http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable
  ...becomes...
Section: stable


https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public
  ...becomes...
Section: public
```

**Step 5**: Put it all together, and format it properly. Recall that the format is: `"Origin:Section";`. The quotes and the trailing semicolon are essential formatting elements.

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security
Origin: Ubuntu
Section: focal-security
Formatted line for Unattended Upgrades: "Ubuntu:focal-security";

http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable
Origin: Google LLC
Section: stable
Formatted line for Unattended Upgrades: "Google LLC:stable";

https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb/ public
Origin: Artifactory
Section: Public
Formatted line for Unattended Upgrades: "Artifactory:public";
```

**Step 6**: Add the line to the correct section of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`.

Test it: Run `sudo unattended-upgrade`, then check the logfile at `var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` to ensure that it ran without error and that your source was properly included.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and helpful answer. It works now :)