# unattended updates don't update anything for me

Tags: apt, updates

I'm relatively new to ubuntu from fedora, I'm looking for alternative for dnf-automatic. That one you configured and all is applied by default, which is what I'm looking for. Update all immediately, don't reboot, notify about such update. I've been following this how-to https://linoxide.com/enable-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-20-04/ however it never updates anything.

systemd job is running, configuration seems sound to me, yet nothing. Can someone suggest how to fix that? Maybe Allowed-Origins arent fine, how to transform sources.list.d into Allowed-Origins list?

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};
Unattended-Upgrade::DevRelease "auto";
Unattended-Upgrade::MinimalSteps "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Mail "alfonz19@gmail.com";
Unattended-Upgrade::Skip-Updates-On-Metered-Connections "true";
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that Unattended Upgrades never updates anything? Have you reviewed `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log` to confirm that UU isn't doing anything? I saw a lot a activity on May 20 and May 25, though your dates may differ slightly.

Comment: INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-inf
ra-security

INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals ~ It's always like this. While apt repeatedly see stuff to install. So I'd like to somehow update configuration to: "install-it-all-now".

Comment: UU works just fine and has for years for just about everybody else. Please edit your question to present a specific discrepancy ("*UU missed packages A, B, and C on blah date*") and we can help you troubleshoot. Your apt logs would have that detailed information. There is no "do everything" config setting in Unattended Upgrades, since that would likely break a lot of systems.

Comment: @user535733 it's great that it works, then just settings is incorrect. I think the question is spelled correctly. But let me reformulate it here. I don't want to ever again see `sudo apt update` returning anything to be installed(only very fresh updates). I want every update from whichever source to be installed within 1h after release, and automatically.Just like with dnf-automatic. I accept, that UU works for years for everyone, but configuration in question failed to install anything in last few days. I just need to update the config a little somehow, so that it actually install everything.

Comment: There is no "do everything" config. You must specify each UU source. We can offer more specific advice if you specify which source isn't being picked up, or you post the complete output of `sudo apt update` in your question above so we can see your sources. Your original claim is that UU is not working. Has that changed?

Comment: @user535733 I never said it's not working(theoretically).I said it does not update anything for me, which is correct.Ideally I'd like to have answer, which others can apply as well, not just solution for me. Or I will add one repo and will be again clueless. So please, lets try to do it in generic way. I have sources in directory /ec/apt/sources.list.d. HOW to turn this sources into configuration, which UU can use and can actually update EVERYTHING. Sample source? `deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   jammy stable`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1286233/19626 for step-by-step instructions of how to convert that source into an Unattended Upgrades config line. WARNING: What you envision may be dangerous -- UU will do exactly what you told it to do, heedless of the consequences. If an untested third party upgrade breaks your system, then you will wake up one morning with a broken system. Choosing which sources to trust is important.

Comment: @user535733 thanks, I need to check it, but it seems to be what I was looking for. I will verify it, but the process seems really not that easy to do everytime I add new source. I understand, it's the price for getting extra functionality. And thanks for info, I'll try it. But maybe trivial cronjob `bash -c 'apt update && apt upgrade -y'` is better way if you really don't want any extra stuff. I don't know.