# Unattended Upgrades for new Mozilla Firefox apt repository

Tags: apt, firefox, repository, debian, mozilla

[Mozilla's new apt repository for Firefox](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04) is not used by Unattended Upgrades.

Comment: This question already has an answer here: [Unattended upgrades doesn't upgrade additional repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286222/unattended-upgrades-doesnt-upgrade-additional-repository)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the `"Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins"` section in the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
    "namespaces/moz-fx-productdelivery-pr-38b5/repositories/mozilla:mozilla";
```

More info in [Unattended upgrades doesn't upgrade additional repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286222/unattended-upgrades-doesnt-upgrade-additional-repository)